# Try-with-resources when returning a resource

Tags: java, stream, try-catch, outputstream

Will following code work?

```
public ConvertibleOutputStream toOutputStream(Type type, Details 
details) 
  {
    try(ConvertibleOutputStream outputStream = new ConvertibleOutputStream();) {
        details.toJson(outputStream);
        return outputStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}
```

The stream is initialized in try-with-resources block and returned in try block. Will the stream get closed before returning? Should I be writing the code in below format instead:

```
public ConvertibleOutputStream toOutputStream(Type type, Details 
details) 
  {
   ConvertibleOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try{
        outputStream = new ConvertibleOutputStream();
        details.toJson(outputStream);
        return outputStream;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new CustomException();
            }
        }
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Your second code block won't compile. Your first code block *will* close `outputStream` before returning, so depending on what `ConvertibleOutputStream` is/does, it may be meaningless. If it works like [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), then it'll work, because closing will prevent writing of more data, but doesn't clear the accumulated data. In that case, however, it would be more appropriate to not return the `OutputStream`, but the result, i.e. `return outputStream.toByteArray​();`.

Comment: I fixed the second code. 

Functionality works with first code, but after reading more on try-with-resources I thought it should not work. ConvertibleOutputStream does extend from ByteArrayOutputStream. I am trying to avoid additional copies of data and inturn not converting to byte array i.e, outputStream.toByteArray​().